# Show that $(a+b+c)^\alpha<a^\alpha+b^\alpha+c^\alpha, 0<\alpha<1$

Tags: real-analysis

For any positive real $ a, b, c$, show that $(a+b+c)^\alpha<a^\alpha+b^\alpha+c^\alpha,  0<\alpha<1$.

I can show that it works for special cases like $\alpha=1/p, p\in\mathbb{N}$... but I don't know how to generalize further...

Comment: How would you show it for the special cases? Why doesn't it generalize?

Comment: I would show by raising both sides to the $p$ power and using the binomial theorem on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calvin Lin's answer seems sufficient. However, here are a few extra notes:

- It suffices just to show $(a + b)^\alpha < a^\alpha + b^\alpha$.
- That would in turn follow from $(1 + x)^\alpha < 1 + x^\alpha$ for $1 \geq x > 0$.
- Or in other words that $\frac{(1+x)^\alpha - 1}{x} < x^{\alpha-1}$. By the mean value theorem, the left side is of the form $\alpha c^{\alpha-1}$ for some $c$ strictly between $1$ and $1+x$. We have $\alpha c^{\alpha-1} < c^{\alpha-1} < x^{\alpha-1}$, since $\alpha-1 < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the tag of real-analysis, I will use calculus.

**Hint:**  Show that we have equality when $ a=b=c=0$.

**Hint:** Differentiate both sides with respect to each variable. Show that

$$ \alpha ( a + b + c )^{\alpha-1} \leq \alpha a^{\alpha -1 },$$

where equality holds if and only if $ b=c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it is enough to prove it for special case $a+b+c=1$.